# Why is \centering{}aligning text above it?? (basic question)

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am new to LaTeX and am trying to get used to the features of the language. I have typed

```
\indent Like all languages mathematics has a few basic rules upon which its complexity is built. The first, and most important rule is this:
        \centering{No statement may be ambigous. That is, it must be either true or false. These statements are known as \underline{predicates}.}
```

SO I want the standard alignment except for the sentence I put in the centering brackets. Why is the whole paragraph ending up centered?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It should be `\begin{center}No statement may be ambigous. That is, it must be either true or false. These statements are known as \underline{predicates}.\end{center}`

Comment: The alignment in effect at the end of a paragraph is applied to that paragraph. Hence, the text before `\centering` is centred here. And, as mentioned above, it does not take an argument. The `center` environment may be more suitable.

Comment: I bet mathematics does not really call propositions 'predicates'. Freger would turn in his grave.

Comment: @s__C try `Text {blabla \centering blabla} Text\par` ;)

Comment: @s__C the alignment of a paragraph is whatever is active *when the paragraph ends* which is why a `\par` should be added: `{blabla \centering blabla\par}`.

Comment: Frege would probably spin....

Comment: @s__C a blank line *outside* of the `{...}` is useless for the same reason why `{blabla \centering blabla}\par` won't give centered text.